# How to Display Custom Post Type's Gallery (images ) in Through WP_Query

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to load an Image Slider images from a Custom Post Type image  Gallery Feature. For example let say I have an Custom Post Type called `banner` which I can load images to it's Gallery and I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="item active">
  <img src="assets/img/ban1r.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    slide 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item active">
  <img src="assets/img/ban2r.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    slide 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please let me know how I can use the custom WP_Query to retrive the images from the custom post and load them into slider instead of above HTML?

So far I have done something like this but it is not displaying any image!

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banner');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images($post);
foreach( $gallery as $image ) {
       echo '<div class="item active">';
       echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';
       echo '</div>';
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this before 2 months ago, and working great for me.

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "select * from $wpdb->posts 
             where 
             post_type = 'banner' and 
             post_status = 'publish'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

foreach( $results as $result ){

    echo '<div id="'.$result['ID'].'" class="listen">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $result['ID'], array(200, 200) );
    </div>';

}
```

Take a look on [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: Hi Jogesh_pi , thanks for comment but I guess your solution is getting the post,s Featured Image (formerly called Post Thumbnail). But I need to retrieve the Post associated Gallery