# How to retrive Custom Post Type Meta Fields in Custom WP_Query

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Can some one let me know How I can render the Custom Post Type Meta Fields (Meta-boxes).
I have a Custom Post Type Called "News" and I successfully added a metabox to my Custom Post Type called "News Info" which is suppose to store : 
A TextField = News Resource 
A Select option = News Type 
A check box

[image]

I can retrieve the Custom post Type "News"content using a custom Loop as:

```
<?php
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'news');
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
 endwhile;
?>
```

But I have no idea how to get the associated meta fields to "news" posts? trust me I Google this a lot but couldn't find any solution all of them just tried to render the Metabox on the admin page but no sample for presenting on the page!
Can you please let me know how I can get access and render the data on the page using the wp-query loop?

Thanks

Comment: `get_post_meta( $post->ID,'name_of_your_meta',true);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To build upon SidGBF's answer, you can use `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'YOUR_FIELD_NAME',true);`

That is a little verbose if you're going to use it again and again, so it might be helpful to add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function get_custom_field($field_name){
  return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$field_name,true);
}
```

Then you can just use `get_custom_field('YOUR_FIELD_NAME')`.

If you'd like to print the value of the field, use `echo get_custom_field('YOUR_FIELD_NAME')`

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your perfect solution, however I am going to ask you to do me a favor and take a look at this post as well?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722768/how-to-display-custom-post-types-gallery-images-in-through-wp-query I have posted the question few days agao but not get any good feedback on it?!

Comment: This was helpful! Shouldn't this question be on wordpress.stackexchange.com though?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution may be found in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta . To get the post's ID you may use `get_the_ID()`.